# Avoiding over-booking as a result of race conditions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We are considering a reservation system where there are two models involved: `Store` and `Reservation`. `Store` has `max_seats` and `Reservation` has `guests_count` column.

To avoid overbooking, we have implemented validation. In case of an overbooking, the transaction is rolled back. But I am unsure if this is foolproof enough against race conditions.

Like so:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
  validates :max_seats, presence: true, numericality: true
end

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  validates :guests_count, presence: true, numericality: true

  after_create do
    total_seats_taken = reservation_slot.reservations.sum(&:guests_count)
    unless total_seats_taken <= store.max_seats
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
end
```

I am suspecting this scnenerio can still happen, even though it would be rare:

Assume that Customer A and Customer B are making a reservation of 6 seats individually, exactly at the same time, and `max_seats` is set as 10. If the transaction of Customer A is committed before Customer B performs `after_create` callback, `ActiveRecord::Rollback` exception is raised and the record for Customer B is not created, which is intended. However, if `after_create` callback is performed before the transaction of Customer A being commited, I think it will result in an overbooking situation.

A starts transaction -> A performs `after_create` -> A commits transaction -> B performs `after_create`: B encounters `ActiveRecord::Rollback` exception

A starts transaction -> A performs `after_create` -> B performs `after_create` -> A commits transaction: Overbooking!!

If you could share any insights, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use a before_create instead?  You can do it your way but why would you ever want to start the process of writing it to your database and raise an exception if you don't need to?